# Position div relative to previous div

Tags: html, css

The objective of [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/j8exhsxz/) is to have the second div positioned in coordinates relative to the first div. For example, if the top/left of the first div is 160/160, then I need the second div to be positioned top + 100 = 260, left + 200 = 360. Is this possible?

HTML

```
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:160px">
 this is the first div
</div>

<div style="background-color:orange;width:160px;position:absolute">
 this second  second div
</div>
```

Comment: your question is not so clear.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j8exhsxz/3/ check this.

Comment: This is js option https://jsfiddle.net/j8exhsxz/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than 1 way to do that, this one is without `position: absolute`, and which way to choose depends very much on what the expected behavior is.

Using `position: relative` will keep the 2:nd div within the page flow, so will `margin`, and `position: absolute` and `float` will take it out of the flow (in somewhat different ways though).

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color:yellow;width:160px
}
.div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color:orange;width:160px
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 this is the first div
</div>

<div class="div2">
 this second  second div
</div>
```

Using `position: absolute` you can position them exactly where you want.

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 160px;
  background-color:yellow;width:160px
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
  left: 360px;
  background-color:orange;width:160px
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 this is the first div
</div>

<div class="div2">
 this second  second div
</div>
```

Comment: while the `top` will be relative to the other element, the `left` will not.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody That's is correct in this case, but saying _within the page flow_ is still also correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

if that is all you need, here's an option:

```html
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:160px">
  this is the first div
</div>
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
<div style="background-color:orange;width:160px;margin-left:200px">
  this second second div
</div>
```

there are many more ways, like position:absolute, or even more complicated stuff like flexbox. but that's a fast route.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways. Using margin or using positioning. Margin will be more flexible and recommended. Either way, I want you to see the difference:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1">
 this is the first div
</div>

<div class="box2">
 this second  second div
</div>
<br>
<div class="box3">
 this is the first div
</div>

<div class="box4">
 this second  second div
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box1, .box3{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:160px
}
.box2, .box4{
    background-color:orange;
    width:160px
}

.box2{
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.box3{
    position: absolute;

}
.box4{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left:200px;
}
```

Try it here in this [**demo**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/GoQXMZ)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can position the 2 elements relative to each other.

```
var secondTop = parseInt($('.first').css('top'), 10) + 100 + 'px';
var secondLeft = parseInt($('.first').css('left'), 10)  + 200 + 'px';
$('.second').css({top: secondTop, left: secondLeft});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/yx6q06o0/).

Expanding on this, you could store the amount you want the 2nd element offset using the `top` and `left` properties, like this:

```
var secondTop = parseInt($('.first').css('top'), 10) + parseInt($('.second').css('top'), 10) + 'px';
var secondLeft = parseInt($('.first').css('left'), 10)  + parseInt($('.second').css('left'), 10) + 'px';
$('.second').css({top: secondTop, left: secondLeft});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var secondTop = parseInt($('.first').css('top'), 10) + parseInt($('.second').css('top'), 10) + 'px';
    var secondLeft = parseInt($('.first').css('left'), 10)  + parseInt($('.second').css('left'), 10) + 'px';
 $('.second').css({top: secondTop, left: secondLeft});
});
```

```css
.first {
 position: relative; 
  background-color: yellow; 
  width: 160px; 
  top: 160px;
  left: 160px;
}

.second {
 background-color: orange; 
  width: 160px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
 this is the first div
</div>

<div class="second">
 this second  second div
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/nr2vnhrs/);